# How does the (Main Weapon) tag work in Only War?

Tags: warhammer-40k, only-war

I haven't been able to find any explanation on what the significance of the tag (Main Weapon) is or how it affects the rules except that it obviously point out the main weapon in a regiment.

Which brings me to my question. In Table 2-6 Additional Standard Kit Items you are able to switch out weapons for another weapon such a laspistol for a lascarbine. However, all those weapons have the tag (Main Weapon). Does that mean you can only switch the weapon if it has that tag?
For examples rough rider regiment gets a laspistol and a hunting lance as their arms. However, it is the hunting lance that has the (Main Weapon) tag so does that prevent a rough rider regiment to switch the laspistol for a lascarbine?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can only swap the laspistol for another main weapon if it has the 'main weapon' tag.

Yes, this prevents the Rough Riders from swapping out their laspistol, as it's no longer their main weapon.

This is presumably because it's possible to finish Regiment creation with only the laspistol as your main weapon, depending on doctrines and regiment types. Obviously not ideal, so they give you the option to swap it relatively cheaply.

However, most Regiments will have swapped their laspistol for a different main weapon as a result of regiment creation, so they don't need the option. In the case of the Rough Riders, I suspect they didn't want players gaming the system to get both the hunting lance and a decent ranged weapon without paying for it.

If you want to get around this and have both the lascarbine and the hunting lance, you can get a lascarbine as additional kit by using your points to get a 'common availability item' from the bottom of the table.

--slight edit for clarity